# Client has set up a mirror on DreamHost, but original site is hosted elsewhere

Tags: subdomain, dreamhost, mirror

Sorry. Newbie here.

Picked up a client that needs has a blog through LexBlog. They want to recreate it on DreamHost and move all of the information over.

She puchased her hosting through DreamHost and added the current domain. Then set up a mirror site. I have never used DreamHost or a mirror. Question is, will the mirror even work since the original site is hosted elsewhere? Or should a basic subdomain be set up to build the new site on before we make the switch over.